# What is Apigee?

Tags: web-services

Sounds like a very simple question.

What is Apigee?. I hear people at work saying react.js front end is going to call Apigee.

Could any one point me in the right direction.

Comment: *I hear people at work saying react.js front end is going to call Apogee.* Ask the people at work.

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/243725). And the Apogee Software I'm familiar with makes [video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_Realms); so I'd suggest you ask the people who are talking about it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:-

```
https://apigee.com/about/cp/what-apigee

https://apigee.com/about/in-the-news/apigee-how-monetise-api

ApiGee is pronounced as ah-pa-gee
```

Answer (score 1):

Apigee Edge is an API Gateway from Google
You can create a proxy layer for all your apis
to Know more about Apigee
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/get-started/get-started

Comment: This is right answer. it's an API management platform.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, through apigee you can apply as many policies for your endpoint ( to have it more secure)
For example, OAuth (authentication ), shared policies, fault, error handling, setting quota limits, xmltojson conversion, transformation logics etc.

https://javabelazy.blogspot.com/